# Matrix year to year percentage calculation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Looking for a way to calculates the yearly growth in ssrs matrix. for eg. for May 2017 it ll do- (May-2017-May2016)/May2016.

Attached the screenshot. Unit is a column. I am using running values function inside the data .

Row group- Type
Column Group- Date

Thanks.

#### example

[image: example]

Comment: is it possible to do so in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the similar solution of your problem -
Following are the tables and data used for report creation-
create table dslocation
(
locationId int
 ,    locationName varchar(20)
  ,   mmpremium int
  , sspremium int
)
INSERT INTO dslocation
VALues (1, 'SANDY', 1000,'')
,(2, 'RANSY', 2000,'')

create table prevdslocation
(
plocationId int
 ,    plocationName varchar(20)
  ,   pmmpremium int
  , psspremium int
)

INSERT INTO prevdslocation
VALues (1, 'SANDY', 2000,'')
,(2, 'RANSY', 3000,'')

Then add a column and write following expression in placeholder-
=Fields!mmpremium.Value-join(LookupSet(Fields!locationId.Value,Fields!plocationId.Value,Fields!pmmpremium.Value,"prevdslocation"),",")

Following is the screenshot of the solution -
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```